# MongoDB Console - Find & pull object in an array based on nested object with regex

Tags: mongodb

I have run into a problem where I need to delete some entries in my database based on a regexp that looks for an 'x' char in the value of the field. This is my data structure:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5e0effac04d45483d97cb4c3"),
 "formId" : ObjectId("5d076f7db166bcae2743554a"),
 "revisionNo" : 0,
 "customerUserId" : ObjectId("5d0889fde55fbc38509e5825"),
 "formElements" : [ 
    {
        "formElementId" : ObjectId("5d1a047cae7a711848238c26"),
        "type" : "text",
        "label" : "Intersection number",
        "value" : null,
        "dynamicTypeData" : {
            "required" : false,
            "value" : "TK47ax"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "formElementId" : ObjectId("5d1a058cae7a711848238c27"),
        "type" : "select",
        "label" : "Municipality",
        "value" : null,
        "dynamicTypeData" : {
            "attributes" : null,
            "options" : [ 

            ],
            "required" : false
        }
    }, 
    {
        "formElementId" : ObjectId("5d00ec9a9001eb637c8466f4"),
        "type" : "select",
        "label" : "Signtype for setup",
        "value" : null,
        "dynamicTypeData" : {
            "attributes" : null,
            "options" : [ 

            ],
            "required" : false
        }
    }, 
    {
        "formElementId" : ObjectId("5d00ee749001eb637c8466fc"),
        "type" : "select",
        "label" : "Sign size",
        "value" : null,
        "dynamicTypeData" : {
            "attributes" : null,
            "options" : [ 

            ],
            "required" : false
        }
    }, 
    {
        "formElementId" : ObjectId("5d00eced9001eb637c8466f5"),
        "type" : "select",
        "label" : "Route number",
        "value" : null,
        "dynamicTypeData" : {
            "attributes" : null,
            "options" : [ 

            ],
            "required" : false
        }
    }, 
    {
        "formElementId" : ObjectId("5d00eeba9001eb637c8466fe"),
        "type" : "select",
        "label" : "Stand",
        "value" : null,
        "dynamicTypeData" : {
            "attributes" : null,
            "options" : [ 

            ],
            "required" : false
        }
    }, 
    {
        "formElementId" : ObjectId("5d00ee849001eb637c8466fd"),
        "type" : "select",
        "label" : "Foundation",
        "value" : null,
        "dynamicTypeData" : {
            "attributes" : null,
            "options" : [ 

            ],
            "required" : false
        }
    }, 
    {
        "formElementId" : ObjectId("5d00ed0f9001eb637c8466f6"),
        "type" : "textarea",
        "label" : "Remarks regaring the new signs placement",
        "value" : null,
        "dynamicTypeData" : {
            "value" : null,
            "required" : false
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

So what I want to find is every element matches the `label: "Intersection number"` with a value that contains the char `x` in their `dynamicTypeData` object. I'm aware that I can in the console do something like: `db.getCollection('formRegistrations').find({formId: ObjectId("5d0889fde55fbc38509e5825")}) but how to get all the way down to the`dynamicTypeData` object and match with the value in that, I have no idea. Please Help :) Thanks for reading

**EDIT**

While the given answer is correct I still only wanted to **find** the given registrations with those parameters, because I had to manually review the data before deletion since this was done on a production ser. So from the answer given below I formulated my own script:

```
db.formRegistrations.find(
    {
        formId: ObjectId("5d076f7db166bcae2743554a"),
        "formElements.0.label": "Intersection number",
        "formElements.0.dynamicTypeData.value": {
            $regex: /.*x/
        }
    }
)
```

Hope this helps someone other than myself

Comment: As from the above link, For multiple documents :: `db.getCollection('formRegistrations').updateMany( { 'formElements.label': "Intersection number"},
{ $pull: { 'formElements':  {'dynamicTypeData.value' : /x/}} } )` Or for a specific document :: `db.getCollection('formRegistrations').update( { "_id" : ObjectId("5e0effac04d45483d97cb4c3"), 'formElements.label': "Intersection number"},
{ $pull: { 'formElements':  {'dynamicTypeData.value' : /x/}} } )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `formElements` matching a specific `label` and `dynamicTypeData`(child elements) value, this should work :

```
db.formRegistrations.update({ _id: <the id> }, {
  $pull: {
    formElements: {
      "label": "Intersection number",
      "dynamicTypeData.value": {
        $regex: /^.*?x.*$/,
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  }
})
```